# проблема с IntelliSence VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

В vs 2017 и до него Intellisense работал просто отлично. Я набирал текст, не важно с большой буквы, с ошибкой - visual studio сам выбирал вариант, подсвечивал его. Мне было достаточно нажать Enter и подтвердить. Это неплохо так увеличивало скорость написания кода.

[image: Заметьте класс автоматически подсвечивается.]

[image: Выделение автоматическое, достаточно нажать Enter]

Заметьте класс автоматически подсвечивается.Нажимаю на скобку, автоматически вставляется правильный вариант.
А в VisualStudio 2019 получается такая штука:

[image: текст автоматически не подсвечивается]

[image: текст автоматически не подсвечивается]

Приходится нажать стрелку "вниз" или "вверх", выделить его и только потом срабатывает "автодописывание".
Можно ли как-нибудь вернуть "удобства" из vs2017? Где в настройках копать?

Comment: Что-то не то у вас. Попробуйте сбросить настройки. У меня "из коробки" все работает, как вы описали.

Comment: А если нажать кнопку табуляции в момент выбора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переключите режим подсказок, кнопка называется "Toggle between suggestion and standard completion modes (Ctrl+Alt+Space)".

Если его выключить, то будет сразу выделять все строку и автоматом дополнять её по Enter:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есил включить - переносить на новую строку (без дописывания):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]